# Laravel: Updating hasMany/BelongTo relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a master table `jobs` with multiple location in separate table `job_location`. Now I am not able to update/delete, if extra rows found from `job_location`. Now why I am saying `DELETE` is because `sync()` did this, but it's related to many-to-many relation. I am new to laravel, just trying to get eloquent approach to achieve this, otherwise deleting all rows and inserting can be done easily OR updating each and delete remaining is also an option but I wonder Laravel has something for this.

In every request I get multiple job locations(with unchanged/changed city,phone_number,address) which is creating trouble.

Some codeshots:

**Model: [Job.php]**

```
class Jobs extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_id_pk', 'job_name','salary'
    ];


    public function joblocation() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\JobLocation', 'job_id_fk', 'job_id_pk');
    }

}
```

**Model:[JobLocation.php]**

```
class JobLocation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'jobl_id_pk', 'job_id_fk','city', 'address', 'phone_number'
    ];


    public function job() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Jobs', 'job_id_fk', 'job_id_pk');
    }

}
```

**Controller:[JobController.php]**

```
function jobDetail() {

    if($params['jid']) {    
        // update
        $obj = \App\Jobs::find($params['jid']);
        $obj->job_name = $params['name'];
        $obj->salary = $params['salary'];
        $obj->save();
    } else {        
        // create new
        $data = array(
            'job_name' => $params['name'],
            'salary' => $params['salary'],
        );
        $obj = \App\Jobs::create($data);
    }

    // don't bother how this $objDetail has associative array data, it is processed so
    foreach ($params['jobLocations'] AS $key => $objDetail) {
        $jobLoc = new \App\JobLocation;
        $jobLoc->city = $objDetail['city'];
        $jobLoc->phone_number = $objDetail['phone_number'];
        $jobLoc->address = $objDetail['address'];

        $jobLoc->job()->associate($obj);
        $obj->jobLoc()->save($jobLoc);
    }

}
```

In this approach I am able to save all job locations, but I am using same function to update also. Please tell how I can update `jobLocations` if present. I am ok to loose previous entries, but it would be good if previous gets updated and new get entered OR if we have extra entries they get deleted. I know sounds weird but still guide me a way.

Comment: Maybe something like this could help out it loops through all joblocations for the given job.
 `$job = Job::find(ID);
JobLocation::where('id',$job->id)->get(); //<-- loop with the foreach through this?`

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you cannot use the same function, do this

```
$jobs =   \App\Jobs::find($params['jid']);

foreach ($params['jobLocations'] as $key => $objDetail) {
     $joblocation = $jobs->joblocation->where('jobl_id_pk', $objDetail['some_id'])->first();

     //here update you job location

     $joblocation->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Controller:[JobController]

public function jobDetail() {

    if( !empty($params['jid']) ) {    
        // update
        $job = \App\Jobs::find($params['jid']);
        $job->job_name = $params['name'];
        $job->salary = $params['salary'];
        $job->save();
    } else {        
        // create new
        $data = array(
            'job_name' => $params['name'],
            'salary' => $params['salary'],
        );
        $job = \App\Jobs::create($data);
    }

    $locationDetails = !empty($params['jobLocations']) ? $params['jobLocations'] : [];

    $jobLocations = array_map(function($location) use($job) {
        $location = array_merge($location, [ 'job_id_fk' => $job->job_id_pk ]);
        return \App\JobLocation::firstOrNew($location);
    }, $locationDetails);

    $job->jobLocations()->saveMany($jobLocations);

}
```